# Why does a query of one catalog in one tab automatically show the same query and any results in a second tab searching a different catalog?

Tags: html, asp.net, database, search

This is my first post. I'm not a web programmer and I'm trying to understand why what seems like strange behavior occurs in Chrome and IE.

We have two product catalogs hosted on one server and when I search for a product by id number in the first, then open a new tab to search the second catalog, the id number I just searched for plus any search results for it appear in the new tab straight away.

I've substituted the server name and directory for numbers, but maybe it's helpful to see that the only difference between the catalogs are the directories they're in (1 and 2).

https://123/Client/1/GetForm.aspx

https://123/Client/2/GetForm.aspx

I appreciate any insight you can offer.